# POST JSON data with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json, post, httpwebrequest

I had below code to call a POST method with json body, but I getting `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` when it execute the code of `using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())`.

My code only worked fine if there is no data-raw required.

**Sample json**

```
{"redirect":"www.google.com","subscriptionTypeId":76670001,"marketingCampaign":{"conversionId":12345,"agency":"","medium":"","name":"","source":""}}
```

**My Code**

```
public static bool HTTPRequest(string URL, RequestMethod CallMethod, Hashtable RequestHeaders, string json, ref StringBuilder httpRequestHeader, ref string jsonResponse, bool preparepurchaseFlag)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = CallMethod.ToString();
            request.ContentLength = 0;

            //Header
            if (RequestHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (string ParamKey in RequestHeaders.Keys)
                {
                    if (ParamKey == "Content-Type")
                    {
                        request.ContentType = RequestHeaders[ParamKey].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (ParamKey.ToLower() == "accept")
                    {
                        request.Accept = RequestHeaders[ParamKey].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        request.Headers[ParamKey] = RequestHeaders[ParamKey].ToString();
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            //Body
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);

                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            //Log Request Header
            httpRequestHeader.AppendLine("curl --location --request " + request.Method.ToString());
            httpRequestHeader.AppendLine(request.RequestUri.ToString());

            foreach (string ParamKey in RequestHeaders.Keys)
            {
                httpRequestHeader.Append("--header ");
                httpRequestHeader.AppendLine(ParamKey + ": " + RequestHeaders[ParamKey].ToString());
            }

            if (preparepurchaseFlag)
            {
                httpRequestHeader.Append("--data-raw ");
                httpRequestHeader.AppendLine(json);
            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new Exception(message);
                }

                var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
                jsonResponse = responseValue;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //catch
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch
        }
    }
```

Comment: `catch (WebException e)` -> why don't you read the response in the catch and see what the server says about your request?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama hmmm I think you are pointing the very valuable comment for me, because the bad requests are numerous, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-7.0) for new development is not recommended by Microsoft. Instead, you should use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) class, which simplifies a lot of the process.

Here is a quick wrapper I created to help you get started.

```
public class HttpClientWrapper
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpClientWrapper(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<T> SendRequestAsync<T>(
        string relativeUrl,
        HttpMethod method,
        object? payload,
        IDictionary<string, string>? queryParameters,
        IDictionary<string, string>? headers)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relativeUrl))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(relativeUrl));
        }

        string relativeUrlWithArguments = AddArgumentsToUrl(relativeUrl, queryParameters);

        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = CreateHttpRequestMessage(relativeUrlWithArguments, method, payload, headers);

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var textResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textResponse))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty response returned by server.");
        }

        T? data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(textResponse);

        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to deserialize the response to your model.");
        }

        return data;
    }

    private static string AddArgumentsToUrl(string url, IDictionary<string, string>? queryParameters)
    {
        queryParameters ??= new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string argumentsString = string.Join("&", queryParameters.Select(arg => $"{arg.Key}={arg.Value}"));
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(argumentsString) ? $"{url}?{argumentsString}" : url;
    }

    private static HttpRequestMessage CreateHttpRequestMessage(string relativeUrl,
                                                               HttpMethod method,
                                                               object? payload,
                                                               IDictionary<string, string>? headers)
    {
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, relativeUrl)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        return httpRequestMessage;
    }
}
```

Simple usage of the class above can be:

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpClientWrapper = new HttpClientWrapper(httpClient);
var response = httpClientWrapper.SendRequestAsync<ResponseClass>(
    relativeUrl: "http://myurl.com",
    method: HttpMethod.Post,
    payload: YourObjectThatWillBeSerializedToJson,
    queryParameters: new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "query1", "value1" }
    },
    headers: new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Accept", "AcceptValue" },
        { "Header2", "Header2Value" }
    });
```

Where `ResponseClass` is the type of which the response JSON will be deserialized to. For `payload`, you have to send your object that will be serialized to JSON. Query parameters and headers are optional and can be passed as dictionary. You could edit the functionality of this wrapper to your liking. For example, if you want to pass an already serialized JSON as payload, you will have to slightly modify the `CreateHttpRequestMessage` method.

Important note: it is recommended to use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to manage your HttpClient instances. I have created a static `HttpClient` in my example, which could also be fine. But the important part here is to NOT create a new instance of `HttpClient` for each request you make.

Comment: Hi Sir, I will try it out, However, may I know the reason or any comparison saying that why Microsoft recommend that not to use HttpWebRequest for new development.